# Read Network folder in node.js

Tags: node.js, networking

I want to read network folder of my users. Users network folder information is stored in database. For example, `\\\\192.168.3.107\\Network` is one of my user network folder. As a user, I have made one of my folder **Network** as `Network folder` and my IP is `192.168.3.107`. Now I want to read all of file inside that network file. I already done this in windows. But I need to implement this on Ubuntu. My code is given below:

```
 const fs = require('fs');

 let testFolder = "\\\\192.168.3.107\\Network";

 fs.readdir(testFolder, function(error, contents) {

   if (error) {
    console.log("read error : ", error);
   } 
   for (let content of contents) {
        console.log("content : ", content);
   }   

});
```

But I always get the following error:

```
 read error :  { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '\\192.168.3.107\Network'
     errno: -2,
     code: 'ENOENT',
     syscall: 'scandir',
     path: '\\\\192.168.3.107\\Network' 
 }
```

As far I know, it means I can't create a network folder.

Any suggestion ??? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you mounted the shared  network folder in Ubuntu ? try using the mount point as path

Comment: Have you solved it? I have the same problem, I set permissions from windows to ubuntu, so I can see the shared folder in Ubuntu, but when i try read the folder from node i get ENOENT too.

Comment: I know this post is old but I have the similar problem. I can read the contents of the folder without problem if I run my application with "node application.js" but if I install my application as a service I get the error "enoent"